# Error while running dotnet core api in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, coreclr, kestrel-http-server

On production server I am trying to run dotnet core api under IIS 8.5 i am getting error

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MySite' with physical root 'D:\MyFolder\'
>   failed to start process with commandline '"" ', ErrorCode =
>   '0x80070057 : 0.

I am able to run my API in `Kestrel` using command prompt without any issue.
However i am not able to invoke the API via IIS. I am getting above error in event viewer.

*Note: I also have development server where i have installed `IIS 8.5`, `.Net Core 1.0.1` and `Windows Server Hosting 1.0.1`. But In development environment i am able to access API via IIS.*

However the error is happening in new production server where i have installed `IIS 8.5`, `.Net Core 1.0.4` and `Microsoft .Net Core 1.0.4 & 1.1.1 - Windows Server Hosting`

Since in production  i can run application in Kestrel with `.Net Core 1.0.4` i dont think its the issue with .net core version.
I am guessing its happening because of `Microsoft .Net Core 1.0.4 & 1.1.1 - Windows Server Hosting`. This version is different in development and production.

**Question**
How do i fix this error?
Where would i find old versions of Windows Server Hosting installation files. ( [they are not here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime))

**Update 1**
Below is final deployed web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

i tried changing processPath to `C:\Program Files\dotnet.exe` with no luck

**Update 2**
and here is [project.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ke3y2s1gs9hszw/project.json?dl=0)

Comment: show your web.config. It's most likely broken.

Comment: @Pawel see update1

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. Initially i deployed my application to `C:\MyFolder` and IIS web site was pointing to `C:\MyFolder` but then i changed the deployment to `C:\MyFolder\Api` but forgot to update IIS website physical path.